# How do I get Google Web App script that opens sheet to run additional script on sheet

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a Web App script that is attached to a button on my Google Site (new). It opens up a Google Sheet. Now, what I want to happen is that another script runs that adds a row to that sheet and positions cursor in cell 1.1 of that row.

The Web App I have currently does open the sheet (let's call that script "A"). And a bound script I have written that resides in a custom menu on that sheet currently works to add a line at the bottom of the sheet and move the cursor to cell 1.1 of that line (let's call that script "B").

So, what I want to do is get the B script added to Script A. I just can't figure out where within A to add B. I have tried multiple different locations and none seem to work. I have also tried various onOpen approaches/locations to no avail.

Here are the scripts:

A:
  Code.gs

```
  function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("go.html")
  .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
  }
```

go.html

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>

 <head>
 <base target="_top">

 <script>
    function getData() {
        window.open("url","_blank");
        } 
</script>
</head>
<body>   
<form>
    <input type='button' onmouseup="getData()" value='Add Song'>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

B:

```
 function addSong() {
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
 var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
 var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow()
 sheet.appendRow([lastRow+1]);
 SpreadsheetApp.flush();
 var range = sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow(), 1);
 SpreadsheetApp.setActiveRange(range);
```

Comment: Been doing some research and it looks like maybe some sort of trigger script needs to be invoked by above, but sort of lost figuring out how and where to create and deploy a trigger.

Comment: Can I ask you about your situation? Are there the script "A" and "B" in the same project or the different project? I think that the solution is changed by the situation. And by the way, what is "A" at the last line?

Comment: The last line "A" is a typo. I edited original question text and removed it.

Comment: Right now, the "A" and "B" scripts are separate, but the point is, I want to add B to A, or better said, get A to trigger B so that A runs and does its thing (opens the sheet) and then triggers B to run and B adds the new row to the sheet and places cursor in cell 1.1 of the new row.

Comment: For further clarification, A is a web app attached to a button on a Google Site and it runs successfully, opening a Google sheet. B is a separate script—part of a larger script that creates a menu to do various things to the sheet, one of which is to add a new row and that script works as well.

Comment: Thank you for replying. For example, how about using a trigger of OnOpen for the script "B"? By this, when the Spreadsheet including the script "B" is opened, the function is automatically run. Is this workaround suitable for your situation?

Comment: Hi Tanaike: Yea, that was exactly what I was thinking, just needed confirmation before I charged down that road. I'll research that and see if I can make it work. Thanks.

Comment: Ruben: Thanks for the edits. I tried to do that, but the code headers were for some reason getting included in with the code, even though they were not indented.

Comment: I have looked at this enough to know what I don't know and need to.

Comment: I have looked at this enough to know what I don't know and need to. (1) On first blush, I thought a "Trigger" was in effect a different classification of script (as bound is different from standalone), but it seems to me, a trigger is simply certain code commands like "onOpen()" or "onEdit()". (2) As such, while onOpen() could work, I do not want to bind an onOpen trigger to my sheet because I do not need it to run on EVERY opening of the sheet, just the ones triggered by my button-attached App Script (the A script). So, I'm still lost as to how to set this up.

Comment: I'm really sorry for my poor English skill. I cannot understand about your latest reply. When a Spreadsheet is opened by the script "A", you want to run the script "B" without using the container-bound script. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Yes. The bound script is in a custom menu on what I call the "Catalog" Sheet. If the user already has that sheet open, they can use the "Add Song" item on that menu (which contains a version of Script B) to add the row for the new song. But if the sheet is not open and the user 's starting point is the Google site (in which the Catalog Sheet is embedded), then they click the button that currently has script A in it which is on the home page of the Google site. That opens the Catalog Sheet and I want it to also run Script B without the user having to use the Add Song menu item.

Comment: You want to run the script "B" only when the script "A" is run. You don't want to run the script "B" when user has already opened the Spreadsheet by user. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Yes. That is correct.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I could think of about what you want. As a next step, can I ask you about your current script? You say ``The bound script is in a custom menu on what I call the "Catalog" Sheet.``. Is the script of spreadsheet using ``onOpen()`` for creating the custom menu? If you are using it, you can add the script for achieving it. If you are not using it, you can achieve it by adding the function. Using the function, you can select whether you run the script "B", when the spreadsheet is opened.

Comment: Yes. It's an onOpen function that creates the menu. addSong is one of the things it does. That is all working and really is not part of this discussion. What I want to know is how to add the row (for the new song) when the A script runs.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I posted an answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your question, I apologize.

Comment: The script A and B may be the same project. That is what I am trying to determine. Is there a way to add B to A in the same project or trigger B from A (in which case, B would be in a different project) so that when user clicks Google website "Add Song" button, the Catalog Sheet is opened, a new row is added, and the cursor is positioned in 1.1 of that row.

Comment: In other words, there is no reason (from my standpoint or my desires) B could not be in same project as A if that is doable. I just don't know how to do it or if it can be done, but it would be my preference.

Comment: I apologize for the inconvenience. About ``The script A and B may be the same project.``. Unfortunately, it cannot active the cell of other Spreadsheet from the script "B" by adding the script "B" to the project which has the script "A", while the value can be added to the last row, because the script is not the container-bound script of the active Spreadsheet. This is the specification. So I could understand that I cannot resolve your issue. I apologize for my poor skill.

Comment: No problem. Appreciate your efforts.